# Help me identify this Bug species

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I found this insect in **Pune/India**. Its body size was less than 1 cm. It was near light source. I suspected it to be Juvenile Thread-legged Bug, but i am not sure. Is my suspicion right or is it some other insect?

[image]

Comment: Yeah the Emesinae family is a good guess. It will be hard to tell what species, but on this page you may find more information about Reduviidae insects in India (pdf available) : https://www.researchgate.net/publication/237676358_A_checklist_of_Indian_Assassin_Bugs_Insecta_Hemiptera_Reduviidae_with_taxonomic_status_distribution_and_diagnostic_morphological_characteristics

Comment: This isn't a juvenile; zooming in shows me wings.  It isn't a member of the Reduviid subfamily Emesinae (the front legs aren't modified for grasping prey); I believe it to be a Stilt Bug (family Berytidae), but not knowing the Indian fauna cannot go any further than that,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is *Pneustocerus gravelyi*, a species of stilt bug that lives in India.

In both of these images, you can clearly see the the bright red coloration of the joint on each leg. The pronotum is also the exact same shape and color, and the bright red abdomen extends beyond the closed wings.

[image]

[image]

[original unmodified image source](https://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/705470-Pneustocerus-gravelyi/browse_photos)

Comment: It certainly seems correct identification. Thank you!